# Does OpenGL depend on a windowing system such as GTK+?

Tags: opengl, gtk

I recently decided to start learning OpenGL, and I have a few questions. Mainly, I am wondering if OpenGL depends on a windowing system such as GTK+ and an extension to the windowing system's API that allows OpenGL regions to be created. I've also seen something along the lines of Xlib on the OpenGL Wiki, which seems to be a more direct connection into the X-Windowing System. Is Xlib just a more basic windowing system, or can windows entirely controlled by OpenGL be created? In the case that both are possible, which is the more widely accepted standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenGL's specification is compelely *agnostic* with respect to window systems. As far as OpenGL is concerned, there are no windows. All there is in this regard is the *system-provided default framebuffer* (FBO 0), which typically is connected to some window - however, this does not have to be the case. For example, there are [pbuffers](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_pbuffer.txt), which are a way to generate an OpenGL context without having a visible window at all.

All of these matters are *platform dependent* and thus outside the scope of OpenGL itself, but a set of platform-dependent APIs:

- [*wgl*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is actually part of the Windows API (as is OpenGL 1.1)
- [*glX*](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glx1.4.pdf), which is the GL interface for the X Window System, so mostly relevant for Linux and UNIX
- on Apple, there is [*CGL*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html) and [NSOpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSOpenGLContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and in the past [*AGL*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/AGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html))
- For embedded systems and GLES, where such window systems typically do not exist, there is [*EGL*](http://www.khronos.org/egl/). While this initially focused on GLES, it is actually capable of also managing GL contexts, and there are ongoing efforts to make this to some kind of *standard API* for HW-accelerated GL context creation on Linux, when the X Window System is going to be replaced by [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/).
- Apple also defines its own GLES context API [`EAGL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/opengles/reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLContext.html), which is especially relevant for iOS devices like iPhone and iPad.

GTK+ on the other hand is just some sort of widget library. It will use the underlying APIs of the platform to do its things, and it will rely on the platform-specific GL context APIs to implement the GL-specific features. It is the same with Qt.

> Is Xlib just a more basic windowing system, or can windows entirely controlled by OpenGL be created?

*xlib* is the library implementing the X protocol, so it is the most low-level API (except of reimplementing the X protocol manually) when you are working with the X Window system. GTK+ will use it on such a platfrom, too.

Windows are never controlled by the GL. You will always need some platform-dependent method to create and manage the windows, and neither OpenGL nor the GL context APIs are going to help you much with that.

If you do just want a window to use with GL, using GUI toolkits like GTK+ or Qt might be overkill. There are some simple OpenGL window and context management libs like [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) or [freeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) (which is the only currently still actively developed implementation of the [GLUT specification](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html)) which are also abstracting the platform-specific APIs. If you are trying to build a game or multimedia software, libraries like [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) and [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) might also be worth a look, as they provide a set of abstractions for other concepts besides GL, especially audio.

Comment: To make this answer even more complete, you could mention toolkits that abstract the window system dependencies across platforms, like GLUT and GLFW.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: True. I actually thought about this. But from GL's viewpoint, they are not much different to the widget libararies and GUI toolkits like GTK and Qt, don't you think? OTOH, using such libraries might be what the question is actually targeting, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, you could say that they are similar in that sense. I look at them as fairly thin abstraction layers for the GL window system interface, while GUI toolkits like Qt have much larger scope. It's up to you, it's a very thorough and high quality answer in any case.

Comment: AGL is actually deprecated on OS X, and in order to create a "window" you have to use NSOpenGL. CGL is fullscreen only.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thanks for the info, I'm really not uptodate with respect to OSX. I updated my answer.